# JSON error encountered when replacing a text box with a Combo Box

Tags: c#, json, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am very new to Visual Studio. I am writing a program that will retrieve the signature of an employee from an API when their name is entered and a "Get user" button is clicked (e.g. if the employee name Jane Doe is entered, the signature "JNDO" will be retrieved from the API string).

The needed information is read successfully when a text box is used to enter the name. However, when I replace the text box with a combo box to suggest names as the user is typing, I receive the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered
> while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.' This exception
> was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
> TimeSheets_Try_11.Controllers.WebAPI.Getsignature(string) in WebAPI.cs
> TimeSheets_Try_11.Form1.button1_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Form1.cs
> [External Code]
> TimeSheets_Try_11.Program.Main() in Program.cs

By using a breakpoint to understand the value, it states that

> String is not JSON formatted <!doctype html>

My JSON string:

```
[{"signature":"JNDO","firstName":"Jane","fullName":"Doe, Jane","lastName":"Doe"}]
```

Code for my windows form:

```
namespace TimeSheets_Try_11

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        WebAPI WA = new WebAPI();
      

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(StaticStrings.UrlIora);
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            comboBox1.DataSource = WA.Getsignature(textBox2.Text);


        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

       
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(AutoCompleteStringCollection combData)
        {
            
            
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form2 p = new Form2();
            p.ShowDialog(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Code calling out my JSON

```
namespace TimeSheets_Try_11.Controllers
{
    class WebAPI
    {
       

        public string Getsignature(string name)
        {

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var cookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(new Uri(StaticStrings.UrlIora), false);
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            wc.Headers.Add("Cookie:" + cookies);
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            string uri = "";

            uri = StaticStrings.UrlIora + name;

            var myJsonResponse = wc.DownloadString(uri);

            Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);

            string signame = myDeserializedClass.ToString();
            return signame;

        }
}
```

Code defining the variables in my JSON:

```
namespace TimeSheet_Try11_Models
{

    public class Employeename
        {
            public string signature { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string fullName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
        
        }


    public class Root
    {
        public List<Employeename> Employeename { get; set; }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: You cannot set the DataSource of ComboBox to a string: make `Getsignature()` return `myDeserializedClass` (so, a `List<Employeename>`). You also need to either set the `ComboBox.DisplayMember` to one of the properties of the `Employeename` class or override `ToString()` (in the same class), to return a composited value. `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` is only useful if you're running this code in Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2-. Otherwise, remove it. +  I don't really understand what's the use of an out-of-session Cookie here (or that Content-Type), but, all right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't personally swap a textbox for a combo to provide autocomplete, I'd set the textbox's `AutoCompleteMode` to e.g. `SuggestAppend` and set its `AutoCompleteSource` to e.g. `CustomSource` then set its `AutoCompleteCustomSource` to an `AutoCompleteStringCollection` built from something like your API responding with a list of all names

```
var acsc = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
acsc.Add("Jane Doe"); // value from API perhaps?
acsc.Add("John Smith"); // value from API query all
```

When the user has had the texbox help them write the names, the name can be submitted to the API to load the rest of the user info

---

A combo would kinda work in advance; download all the data, choose some of it to show in the combo and keep the rest for accessing in the code behind it..

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation and solution. The reason to why the previous methods were causing a JSON error was due to the fact that API was unable to load all possible value. This explanation made me realize it.